# I can't become a vampire lord

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I am playing Skyrim for a really long time, and I am on level 72

I started Dawnguard DLC and I refused Harkon's Gift, but after finishing Dawnguard, a dialogue option appeared with Serana: "I Want You Turn Me Into Vampire".

I chose it, and she bit me, but then everything was normal until I transformed into a vampire lord. Once I turned back, I lost my glowing eyes, teeth and spells and disease stages. The sun doesn't hurt me, and the effects don't show up, but I still have vampire lord powers.

What is going on?

Comment: Please do not capitalize every word in a sentence. It becomes significantly harder to read that way.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what it is you're trying to ask here.  Are you, or are you not, a vampire?  If not, it stands to reason that you wouldn't have the advantages or disadvantages of being a vampire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should try curing yourself and then re-gaining vampirism

Steps to curing Vampirism are located here:

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vampirism_(Skyrim)#Curing_vampirism

Or if it is really necessary...

1. Go to an Inn Keeper as a Vampire and ask "Heard any rumours lately", He/She will say Falion of Morthal has studied Vampires, Draugr and all manors of Undead, then the quest 'Rising at Dawn' will start.
2. Go visit Falion in his house at Morthal, he will tell you that it requires a filled black soul gem, "You're going to have to kill someone".
3. Give him the filled gem and meet him at the summoning circle at about 5am.
4. "Lets get this over with", "I call upon Oblivion Realms.........The Ritual is Complete".

Comment: Can you summarize those steps in your post, so if that link ever dies (because wikia changes how their links are formed, or any other reason) your post still contains all the information?

Comment: @user76190 If this worked for you, please click the checkmark next to this post to accept it as a solution.